# How was my question "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."?

Tags: discussion

This is the link to my question:

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/standards-for-new-hires

Could someone be of any help and improve my question? I have no idea why it is closed, and editing it didn't gain the approval of NickC either.

All i want to ask about is an overview on how companies view their prospective hires (via **GPAs** or **Portfolios**) and how much experience they look for in a new hire via their portfolio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that there are multiple questions being asked there, and that some of those questions are so broad that they cannot be answered with a single answer without knowing more details about the position you're going for and the company hiring.

We generally like our questions to have a single question being asked so that users can focus on it and give a really great single answer to it. We generally don't like questions that prompt for broad, mediocre answers to many questions, or that ask for many different answers, each which may or may not be right depending on circumstances.

Your questions seem to be:

- What would a IT company that is hiring a new graduate fresh from school look at?

  This is an extremely broad question since the answer is different depending on what kind of IT company it is, what kind of position you're applying for, and the company standards and/or culture. Its really hard to answer this with a single answer without knowing more details, and the "correct" answer will vary from company to company.

  If you were to include a few more details, such as the position you're applying for and some details about the company (their size, do they hire a lot of new graduates, etc), you would probably be able to get a great answer to that question.
- Should I focus on and try to sell my GPA or my Portfolio?

  Once again, the answer to this question will largely be determined by the position you're applying for, the company culture, and company standards.

  It would probably stand a better chance on this site if you were to ask two separate questions about how important your GPA or Portfolio is to a hiring manager. The answer will still vary from company-to-company, however I believe there is a single great answer that can be written for that.

  **Edit:** There actually is a question on [how important is a grade point average on a resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/209/316) already. You might want to check out the answers given there.
- How can I prove that my portfolio is credible

  This question should be fine on its own, although include some details about the sort of things your portfolio contains and what part of it you're trying to prove (examples of past work? references? class projects? etc)
- How can I show a company that I have the experience to help the company grow

  This question might also be fine on its own, however it would largely depend on what sort of details you give in the question. It would definitely help if you could explain what sort of experience you have, and how you think it will help the company grow.
- How can I show a company that I am keen to learn more from the company?

  This might also be a decent question if you can clarify what you want to show the company you can learn from them. For example, do you want to show you're interested in the company itself, or that you are a smart individual that can keep learning and teaching yourself new things.

So overall, you have some decent questions, however they're not in the format that Stack Exchange likes to have their questions in. They want to focus on specific questions one at a time, so they can provide a great focused answer to the question.

Your best bet would be to split up the question into multiple questions, each focusing on one question only, and to provide some more details in your question so we can help you by writing some very specific answers to your questions :)

Comment: right, i'll get to that.